# MOSFET Low Voltage Output

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm working on a basic h-bridge motor controller. It will be powering a 48v 1000w motor. The FETs I am using are these ([Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP_B_I50N10S3L_16-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?folderId=db3a3043156fd5730115c7d50620107c&fileId=db3a30431a5c32f2011a9090a32c5962&ack=t)). When I apply the 5v PWM signal from an Arduino Pro Micro with my power source being 48V I get an output of 3.5 volts or -3.5 volts depending on the direction. They seem to be switching correctly but for some reason the output voltage is significantly less then I was looking for.[image] This is a crude schematic that I drew up illustrating my setup. Could this major drop be due to the gate voltage being too low? The data sheet specifies that 2.7V is the gate threshold but almost everywhere it refers to 10V at the gate.  Your time would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using logic-level FETs?  Also, there's no way those high-side FETs are turning on...

Comment: No I haven't, I figured if that was a problem I would build some sort of amplifier circuit. Why do you not believe they are turning on?

Comment: What you say about the gate threshold voltage suggests a misconception. The FET is only just starting to turn on. Here is a short app note from Vishay that will help you understand the issue: https://www.vishay.com/docs/68214/turnonprocess.pdf

Comment: Vgs is from gate to source... the high side source will be changing up to the 48v. So you need to drive that gate with reference to the output...

Comment: Consider using an off the shelf motor controller? It will be far more efficient then your setup here and handle all the drive signals probably better.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the low side FETs should actually be logic level FETs and the high side FETs actually need alot more then 10v at the gate? What would I need on the high side to actually turn them on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get some logic level FETs

FETs whose drain parameters are specified exclusively at 10V aren't going to be on very far with 5V on the gate, which causes them to not work well at all (or fry).  You need *logic level* FETs whose drain parameters are specified at 5V gate-to-source, or some low-side gate driver ICs that can swing the gates of your current FETs to 10V, in order to fix that side and get your low-side FETs on all the way.

### ... and some high-side drivers too

The high-side FETs are a different problem, as their sources will be somewhere near the 48V mark.  This means you need a level-shifting *high side driver* IC or circuit to turn them on and off from your 0-5V logic signals.  This IC shifts the 0V reference of the signal up to whatever voltage the source of the FET is at, as well as provides sufficient drive to the FET.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. So something like this (http://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/91328.pdf) would be a better choice? It says that it is a "Logic Level Gate Drive".

Comment: @MatthewJackaon -- yeah, that FET would work for your low-side NP

Comment: The next question would be for the high-side, would it just be easier to use a P-Channel FET? That would eliminate the fact that it is almost impossible to turn it on currently as I have just learned, correct?

Comment: @MatthewJackaon -- you'd need some sort of level shifting drive anyway, so you might as well get a high-side driver chip

Comment: Wouldn't I need over 53 volts to drive the gate? Those FETs are only rated for +/- 20v Vgs. Besides, a high side driver IC at that voltage seems pretty expensive and rare. Wouldn't a P-Channel FET eliminate the need for that? Wouldn't I be able to turn them on with 10V? I was looking at this one (http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS99912A(IXTA-H-P-Q52P10P).pdf).

Comment: @MatthewJackaon -- the issue with a Pchannel part is the source will have to be pulled all the way up to 48V to turn it off.  The high-side drivers generate the required voltages internally to drive the gate above the source even though the source is at 48V -- you should have no trouble finding HSDs that can put their gate-output 10V above their source pin and can handle the source pin being 48V above ground.

Comment: I think I'm finally understanding. So, I need 10V higher than the source voltage for the gate to turn on. In order to do that I need a high-side driver. So something like this (http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/44405fb.pdf) work? I have a regulated 12V supply that could power this, then, a 5V logic signal from the micro controller. If i'm understanding it correctly it can output 60V max which would be sufficient.

Comment: @MatthewJackaon -- that part would work, yes, if you don't mind the packaging :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use p-channel mosfets on the high side.  Be aware that the gates will need to pull up to near the supply voltage to turn off solidly.  A low budget arrangement would be a pair of resistors such that when the divider is connected between the supply and ground, the gate of the high side fets is pulled down far enough to be in low Rds mode, but not too far as to exceed the GS specification.  Then, you use a logic level n-channel mosfet between the bottom of the divider and ground, which is on when the output is high, grounding the divider.  When the n-channel driver fet is off, the divider pulls up to the supply voltage, since the gate draws almost no current.  Choose resistors such that the switching speed is adequate for your pulse rates, keeping in mind, that you have to have enough current to drive the gate capacitance high in the required turn-off time.  The n-channel inverting transistor needs to be rated for the entire supply voltage DS.

Basic rule of thumb - n-channel enhancement mode is easy on the low side, and p-channel enhancement mode is easy on the high side.  The other way around usually requires an additional supply voltage above (below) the power voltage (ground).
The p-channel device for the same Rds on is likely a bit more expensive than the n-channel device, as it has to be a larger channel because of the device physics.

Of course, as others have suggested, there are driver chips to do the level translation if the resistor network is not fast enough.